# Formal language homework problem - extend(L)

Tags: formal-languages

This is my attempt to solve an exercise from a formal languagues class.

> Consider the following definition:
>
> extend(L) = { w $\in$ $\Sigma^*$ | $\exists$ x $\in$ L, y$\in$ $\Sigma^*$ .  w = xy }

In words: extend(L) is the set of all strings with some prefix in L;

**1- Are CFLs (Context Free Languages) closed under 'extend'? ( If L is CFG, then extend(L) is also CFG?). Justify your answer.**

> Answer: Yes.
>
> Let $G_L$ be the CFG gramar for L . We can construct a new $G_E$ for extend(L) as follows:
>
> S' $\Rightarrow$ SE
>
> E $\Rightarrow$ $a_1$E | $a_2$E | $a_n$E | $\epsilon$
>
> (all other productions from $G_L$
>
> where  S' is the starting symbol for $G_E$; S is the starting symbol for $G_L$ > and $a_1$..$a_n$ are all the symbols from $\Sigma$

Is this correct?

**2- Recursively Enumerable Languages are closed under 'extend' ?**

> Answer: False.

I feel like it is not RE because I can't create a TM for extend(L), but I don't know how to prove it. Reducing another well known undecidable problem to it, perhaps.... but how, and which one?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first part looks okay. For the second, though, $\mathrm{extend}(L)$ appears to be the concatenation of $L$ and $\Sigma^*$, and the r.e. languages are closed under concatenation. Consider a Turing machine $M$ that lists $L$. Modify it so that after listing the $n$-th word of $L$, it systematically lists all of the extensions of the first $n$ words by a maximum of $n$ letters.

Comment: We can't assume anything about the order or size of the strings enumerated by the enumerator of L, since it is RE, right? If the nth work has more than n letters? would we simply generate it as is from the TM of extend?

Comment: @marcos: You modify $M$ to get $M'$ that works as follows. You feed $M'$ the input $1$, and it simulates $M$ with input $1$ **and** generates $w_1a_1,\dots,w_1a_n$. You feed it $2$, and it simulates $M$ with $1$ but outputs $w_1a_ia_j$ for all $i,j$, then simulates $M$ with $2$ and outputs $w_2$, all $w_2a_i$, and all $w_2a_ia_j$. And so on.